# How to use count with conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate how many customers who bought a 'mirror' also bought a 'sofa' within the next 12 months.

Here's a short sample of my data:

```
Customer_id   Product   Gender   Location   Order_date
234324        mirror    m          NY         23-AUG-21
543673        sofa      f          MA         15-Jun-20
842867        sofa      f          CA         12-Feb-18
734938        mirror    m          VA         03-Jan-22
234324        sofa      m          NY         14-May-22
```

I want the results to be two columns: `customer_id` (one value for each customer), and the amount of products they bought within the next 12 months (only if it's 'sofa'). Meaning: I want to count the amount of times they bought 'sofa' only when it's within 12 months since they bought 'mirror'.

Here's what I need to see:

[image]

Here's a query I tried:

```sql
SELECT
    Customer_id,
    COUNT(o2.order_date) cross_sale
FROM
    Orders o1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o2 ON
        o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id
        AND
        o2.order_date > o1.order_date
WHERE
    o1.product = 'mirror'
    OR
    o1.product = 'sofa' 
    AND
    order_date > TO_DATE( '1 Jan 2020', 'DD MON YYYY' )
```

The query is incorrect since it doesn't include the 12 months condition. I tried so many ways, but they didn't work (tried CTE and LEFT JOIN).

How do I calculate 12 months from the previous purchase? It seems very easy, but I'm missing something.

Comment: If the customer buys a mirror in January and another mirror in February, then 2 sofas in March, is that 2 cross sells or 4?

Comment: @bohemian It's 2 since he had 2 sofas purchase.

Comment: I don't know why the question was closed, to me it's clear now. You want do this, don't you?: https://dbfiddle.uk/4vkGNo-n

Comment: It is not that easy. Your main problem: you want to do all at once. You join all orders to all mirror/sofa orders. That already can become a great mess. Lets say a customer bought three mirrors in January, February and June, and two sofas in May and April, and then something else in July, August and December. Your join gets many combinations: 1st order with 7 subsequent orders, 2nd order with 6 subsequent orders, ... = 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 = 25 rows of mirror/mirror, sofa/sofa, mirror/sofa, sofa/mirror, mirror/else, sofa/else.

Comment: Even with only two mirrors and then one sofa, you'd already get two rows, where you want to count only one. It is possible to get this straight with a join only joining what you really want and then counting distinct sofa order numbers / IDs, but using `EXISTS` instead to see whether there was a mirror order that makes a sofa order a match is a better approach.

Comment: If you want to work with a fixed date, as `TO_DATE( '1 Jan 2020', 'DD MON YYYY')` in your query, use a date literal: `DATE '2020-01-01'`. If you want to mix `AND` and `OR`, use parentheses. `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so what you have right now is `WHERE (o1.product = 'mirror') OR (o1.product = 'sofa' AND order_date > DATE '2020-01-01')`, which is not what you want. (Besides you need a table qualifier to express which table `order_date` refers to. Is it `o1` or `o2`?)

Comment: At last, you are showing customers that have no cross_sell in your sample result. Please clarify, which customers you want to see in your results: All customers? All customers who placed at least one order? All customers who placed at least one mirror order? All customers who placed at least one sofa order? ...

Comment: Your table shows a very modern approach to customers by the way. With each order you seem to store the gender, thus considering that customers may change their gender. This enables you to safely count how many women and how many men bought a mirror. Well done :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner By saying "it is not that easy", do you mean the question or the query I proposed in the fiddle above your comment? Do you think my query is correct? It seems so at first glance to me. But to be honest, I didn't have the time to check all possible use cases.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler: I had not even seen your query. I referrred to "It seems very easy, but I'm missing something." in the request. As to your query: It won't work properly when customers buy two or more mirrors within a certain time, and the OP seems to want to show zero counts, too, which your query does not consider. The OP hasn't explained yet, though, which customers to include in the result and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query doing this step by step.

1. Get all sofa orders and all mirror orders.
2. Per customer count sofa orders placed within the year after a mirrors order.
3. Decide wich customers to show in the results. My query shows all customers who either bought one or more mirrors or one or more sofas or both. You may want something else here.
4. Join the counts to the customers. I must outer join, because I am showing customers who bought mirrors only, and these are not included in the sofa count.

The complete query:

```
with
  sofas as
  (
    select *
    from orders
    where product = 'sofa'
  ),
  mirrors as
  (
    select *
    from orders
    where product = 'mirror'
  ),
  counts as
  (
    select customer_id, count(*) as cross_sold
    from sofas
    where exists
    (
      select null
      from mirrors
      where sofas.customer_id = mirrors.customer_id
      and sofas.order_date >= mirrors.order_date
      and sofas.order_date < mirrors.order_date + interval '1' years
    )
    group by customer_id
  ),
  customers as
  (
    select customer_id from sofas
    union 
    select customer_id from mirrors
  )
select customers.customer_id, coalesce(counts.cross_sold, 0) as cross_sell
from customers
left outer join counts on counts.customer_id = customers.customer_id
order by customers.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an OLAP window with a RANGE frame:

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(Customer_id,Product,Gender,Location,Order_date) AS (
          SELECT 234324,'mirror','m','NY',TO_DATE('23-AUG-21','dd-mon-yy')
UNION ALL SELECT 543673,'sofa'  ,'f','MA',TO_DATE('15-Jun-20','dd-mon-yy')
UNION ALL SELECT 842867,'sofa'  ,'f','CA',TO_DATE('12-Feb-18','dd-mon-yy')
UNION ALL SELECT 734938,'mirror','m','VA',TO_DATE('03-Jan-22','dd-mon-yy')
UNION ALL SELECT 234324,'sofa'  ,'m','NY',TO_DATE('14-May-22','dd-mon-yy')
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
check_mirror_bought AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id
  , product
  , SUM(CASE product WHEN 'mirror' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(
      PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date
      RANGE BETWEEN '12 MONTHS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS mirror_bought_lately
  FROM indata
)
SELECT * FROM check_mirror_bought WHERE product = 'sofa';
 customer_id | product | mirror_bought_lately 
-------------+---------+----------------------
      234324 | sofa    |                    1
      543673 | sofa    |                    0
      842867 | sofa    |                    0
```

Comment: `SUM(CASE product WHEN 'mirror' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be simplified to `COUNT(CASE product WHEN 'mirror' THEN 1 END)`, so you don't need an `ELSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Every sofa bought within 1 year of a mirror counts as a cross sell. The trick is to first select sofas, then *inner* join to mirror orders by the same customer within the preceding year, counting with `distinct` to prevent double counting sofas that have multiple mirrors purchased within the preceding year.

```
select
  o1.customer_id,
  count(distinct o1.order_date) as cross_sells
from orders o1
join orders o2 on o2.customer_id = o1.customer_id
  and o2.order_date between add_months(o1.order_date, -12) and o1.order_date
  and o2.product = 'mirror'
where o1.product = 'sofa'
group by o1.customer_id
```

I've used `order_date` as the row identifier for the count, but if there is an `id` column it would be cleaner to use that ie `count(distinct o1.id)`